# c++ method chaining on returned value not working

Tags: c++, scope

I am using cpp after a long time for an opengl project. I am facing a problem which is related to cpp not opengl in particular. What is the difference between the two code snippet bellow?

```
// this works
std::string tmp = FileIO::read("vertex_shader");
const char *vertexShaderSource = tmp.c_str();
std::cout<< vertexShaderSource <<std::endl; //shows proper value

//but this doesn't work 
const char *vertexShaderSource = FileIO::read("vertex_shader").c_str();
std::cout<< vertexShaderSource <<std::endl; //shows garbage value

//FileIO::read() returns a string value
```

I am a bit confused why the first one works but the second one shows garbage? Am i missing something?

Please any cpp experts enlighten me what is wrong on the second code snippet and why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance,

Comment: If this question is based on code you care about for its own sake, instead of code you're looking at just for learning C++, you know that you can just say `std::cout << FileIO::read("vertex_shader") << '\n';`, and just keep the value as a `std::string` instead of converting it to a `char*`.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that but I need a const char* for later use. :)

Comment: It’s still good practice to keep it around as a `std::string`, and only call `c_str()` when you need to. That way you get all the benefits of the `string` class like getting the length in constant time, in addition to not having this current problem of destruction of a temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose `FileIO::read` returns by value, then `FileIO::read("vertex_shader")` returns a [temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) `std::string` which will be destroyed after the full expression. After that `vertexShaderSource` becomes a dangled pointer, any dereference on it leads to UB. i.e.

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = FileIO::read("vertex_shader").c_str();

// vertexShaderSource becomes dangled from here
std::cout<< vertexShaderSource <<std::endl; // UB
```

If use a named variable `tmp` as the 1st code sample showed, `tmp` won't be destroyed until get out of the scope where it's defined; then the code is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `FileIO::read()` returns the `std::string` by value, then when you do

```
FileIO::read("vertex_shader").c_str()
```

the `std::string` object returned by `FileIO::read` is *temporary*. Once its `c_str()` function have been called the object goes out of scope and is destructed, leaving you with a pointer to a string that doesn't exist anymore.

Dereferencing this pointer, which happens when you attempt to print the string, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I kind of guessed that might happen. But storing in a tmp variable doesn't seem so elegant to me. what is the best way too avoid storing it into a tmp variable but still being able to access the variable alive? :)

Comment: @adn.911 Without knowing the actual use-case and problem that's supposed to be solved, we can't really give you a "best way".

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is related to the lifetime of variables. `FileIO::read` returns a `std::string` which holds the string.

In the first case you are copying (actually due to RVO there won't be any copy made) the return value to a variable and then you are getting a pointer to the char array of the string. Thus the memory where that pointer is pointing to is owned by the `tmp` variable.

In the second case, you are retrieving the pointer to a char array owned by the temporary string returned by the `read` function. This gives you a memory address that is owned by the temporary.
After that statement finished, the temporary is destructed along with all the memory it owned which includes the char array pointed by the pointer you retrieved and stored in `vertexShaderSource`.